# Getting ROW_NUMBER to repeat if field meets a condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need ROW_NUMBER to assign data to a specific user if a condition is met.

ROW_NUMBER will increment normally until a duplicate value is found. When the duplicate value is found, I need it to use the same ROW_NUMBER until a new value is found.

For instance...

When using

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COMPANY) AS rownum
      ,Company
      ,Contact
  FROM TABLE
```

We can obviously expect this result

```
rownum     Company              Contact
     1     BOB'S BURGERS        BOB
     2     STEVE'S SARDINES     STEVE
     3     STEVE'S SARDINES     JERRY
     4     STEVE'S SARDINES     MARY
     5     LARRY's LOBSTER      LARRY
     6     CHRIS' COWS          CHRIS
```

What I'm trying to get is this. Whenever the Company name *doesn't* change, repeat the ROW_NUMBER and continue to increment the number when the company does change

```
rownum     Company              Contact
     1     BOB'S BURGERS        BOB
     2     STEVE'S SARDINES     STEVE
     2     STEVE'S SARDINES     JERRY
     2     STEVE'S SARDINES     MARY
     3     LARRY'S LOBSTER      LARRY
     4     CHRIS' COWS          CHRIS
```

I'm using this condition to see if the company matches the previous company name. It returns a 2 if the condition is true

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANY ORDER BY COMPANY) AS SameCompany
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [DENSE_RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) not ROW_NUMBER. Try this:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COMPANY) AS rownum
      ,Company
      ,Contact
  FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Cannot believe it was that easy. I appreciate it!